# Facebook login return account's basic information

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm using facebook login for my website and so far I only have access to these info...

```
{
    authResponse:
    accessToken: "EAA..."
    data_access_expiration_time: 1616474880
    expiresIn: 4320
    graphDomain: "facebook"
    signedRequest: "qT0TN..."
    userID: "154xxxxxxxx"
    status: "connected"
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve basic info such as `first name`, `last name`, `email`, `etc` ?

Since google allows this, I'd assume that facebook also allows access to these basic info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution...

For the sake of those who encountered the same issue.

```
_getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', { fields: 'id,name,email,picture' },
    user => {
      console.log('user details , ', user);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can select your answer as accepted, so it is marked as resolved